# this.props is not a function between parent and children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After setup a simple post component, it would be cool to be able to get the comments from the post.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


import Comments from "../components/comments";

class Post extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            comments: [],

        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.getComments();
    }



    getComments() {
        return axios
            .get("/posts/" + this.props.match.params.id + "/comments")

            .then(result => this.setState({ comments: result.data.comments }))
            .catch(error =>
                this.setState({
                    error
                })
            );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Comments</h2>
                <Comments />              
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Post;
```

so after, place a comment component to get the post comments in the logs start to show

> TypeError: this.props.getComments is not a function

[image]

So, is not possible to pass props from function?
someone has any idea why this issue happen?

**the comments component**

```
import Comment from "./comment";
import axios from "axios";

import Post from "../screens/posts";


class Comments extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comments: [],

      error: ""
    };

    this.load = this.load.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.load();
  }
  load() {
    return this.props.getComments().then(comments => {
      this.setState({ comments });

      return comments;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.comments.map(comment => (
          <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Comments;
```

Comment: Where is `render` function and where do you call `this.props.getComments()` ?

Comment: Where is props set?

Comment: Please add code for comments.jsx

Comment: just a moment i'll place the code

Comment: So, seems ok, right?

Comment: Where is the render function where you render `<Comments />` and pass it the props?

Comment: `<Comments />` <---- you're not passing any props

Comment: @OzzyWalsh is there i just forget to place

Comment: @azium yes i'm i just forget to place it into the textfield

Comment: No you're not `<Comments getComments={this.getComments} />` is passing props... did you forget to add that as well or do you just not have it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the function to Comments as a prop.

You must pass the function as a prop like this:

```
<Comments getComments={this.getComments} />
```

Comment: You should fix the entire problem though... this isn't enough to fix it since the parent function's promise doesn't actually return anything...  state is getting set in both components and it's not going to work the way it currently is written

Comment: @OzzyWalsh thank you.

so, azium, how come the parent function's promise doesn't actually return anything?

Comment: because it's not... you're calling `this.setState()` instead of returning the result

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, but you seem to have some wires crossed with when to use `props` and when to use `state`.

I'm going to have a go at actually fixing this to get it closer to your intended solution, rather than just making it not crash (I'm also going to try not to deviate too much from your style).

**Post.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


import Comments from "../components/comments";

class Post extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            comments: undefined,
            loading: false,
            error: undefined
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadComments();
    }

    // This doesn't return anything, it doesn't need to as the result is getting put into state
    loadComments() {
       this.setState({ 
           comments: undefined,
           loading: true,
           error: undefined
       };
       axios.get("/posts/" + this.props.match.params.id + "/comments")
            .then(result => this.setState({ 
                comments: result.data.comments,
                loading: false,
                error: undefined
            }))
            .catch(error => this.setState({
                loading: false,
                comments: undefined,
                error
            }));
    }

    // Some loading and error states added
    // Note the passing of comments as a prop to Comments
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Comments</h2>
                {this.state.loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                {this.state.error && <div>There was an error - {this.state.error}</div>}
                {this.state.comments && <Comments comments={this.state.comments} />}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Post;
```

**Comments.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Comment from "./comment";

// No longer needs to do any loading or keep any state of its own (it uses props instead), this could be simplified into an Functional Stateless Component (FSC) now if you wanted to.
class Comments extends Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.comments.map(comment => (
                    <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the getComments props in your `Post` render method. Pass them like so:

```
<Comments getComments={this.getComments} />
```